# Ubuntu UFW 3x specific IP addresses only to access a specific port

Tags: firewall

I need to use UFW to allow only 3x different IP addresses to connect on a specific port.
Ex:
IP address [1] - 111.111.111.111
IP address [1] - 222.222.222.222
IP address [1] - 333.333.333.333
on a specific port. All other connections denied.
Any help please?
Can I simply add 3x rules one after each other for each ip address to point at the port?

Answer (score 8):

First lets deny all access:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

Now limit out inbound traffic to `ip` via these `ports`:

```
sudo ufw allow from 1111.1111.1111.1111 to any port 33
sudo ufw allow from 2222.2222.2222.2222 to any port 33
sudo ufw allow from 3333.3333.3333.3333 to any port 33
```

If adding a specific protocol to the rules above:

```
sudo ufw allow from 1111.1111.1111.1111 proto udp to any port 33
```

Now check your rules:

```
sudo ufw status
```

To delete these rules at any time:

```
sudo ufw delete allow from 1111.1111.1111.1111 to any port 33
```

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-14-04