# Can not access to Rabbitmq interface via ip

Tags: 18.04, vps, rabbitmq

I have installed Rabbitmq under ubuntu 18.04 vps and here are the steps

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install erlang
apt-get install rabbitmq-server
systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
systemctl start rabbitmq-server
systemctl status rabbitmq-server
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

rabbitmqctl add_user admin admin
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / admin ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

But when I try to access to the interface via Ip , I can't
http://82.165.112.22:15672

The rabbitmq server is running
[image: The rabbitmq server is running]

This is the output of curl -v http://82.165.112.22:15672

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://82.165.112.22:15672/
*   Trying 82.165.112.22...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 82.165.112.22 (82.165.112.22) port 15672 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 82.165.112.22:15672
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< accept-ranges: bytes
< content-length: 1367
< content-type: text/html  
< date: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 16:56:14 GMT
< etag: "3599625778"
< last-modified: Mon, 02 Sep 2019 16:01:56 GMT
< server: Cowboy
```

[image]

Comment: The port is not open externally, checking it with ` nmap -PN 82.165.112.22 -p 15672` returns `15672/tcp filtered unknown`.

Comment: it returns 15672/tcp open  unknown how to open it ?

Comment: If it says `15672/tcp open`, it should connect. Can you do `curl -v http://82.165.112.22:15672` and paste the output?

Comment: the output is html code of RabbitMQ Management page, I'll add it in the question

Comment: I have added the output

Comment: I'm confused, you're getting the correct html page. Are you running `nmap` and `curl` from outside? or from the same machine where you have rabbitmq running?.

Comment: sorry it was via ssh so in the remote machine.  from my machine I get this output 15672/tcp filtered unknown and I can't access via curl

Comment: i thought so, no problem. [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-an-ubuntu-and-debian-cloud-server), will help you open the port, but i will advice you configure first the [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) with https (possibly using letsencrypt). Also, if you have a static or semi-static ip, [allow access to port 15672 only to your ip](https://askubuntu.com/a/875227/260379).