# UFW Rule - Deny Routes

Tags: ufw, default, traffic

I want to deny all outgoing traffic except to a specific address/address range. I attempted:

```
$ ufw default deny outgoing
$ ufw allow from x.x.x.x to any
$ ufw allow to x.x.x.x from any
```

However, access to `x.x.x.x` is denied.

Comment: Please specify the commands ran, and terminal output - plus the version on Ubuntu you are running. Please ensure you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1242059/edit) your question and not post as a comment.

Comment: Furthermore, if you only want to *allow* a certain host, simply put [a deny](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448836/how-do-i-with-ufw-deny-all-outgoing-ports-excepting-the-ones-i-need) rule on outbound, and an allow for the one host.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to check that you're **actually using** `ufw` as a firewall component - perform the following:

```
root@loopback:/home/mn# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

(Note: This requires root. I **strongly recommend** using `sudo` as opposed to `root`)

The alternative (as you'll see, for me `ufw` is inactive) is to see if you're running `firewalld` -`sudo firewall-cmd --state` should return a value:

```
root@loopback:/home/mn# firewall-cmd --state 
running
```

Now,if you're running `ufw`  you can [check your rules](https://askubuntu.com/a/30916/212930) to see what you have added:

```
sudo ufw show added       # Show user added rules
more /etc/ufw/user.rules  # Show system rules
```

To deny all outbound traffic on `ufw` you would [perform the following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/448836/how-do-i-with-ufw-deny-all-outgoing-ports-excepting-the-ones-i-need):

```
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

Then you [set your allow](https://askubuntu.com/a/875227/212930) hosts.